# Getting the 2nd value in: 1.28 ( 3.93%)

Tags: google-sheets

I used IMPORTHTML to get data from a table and in one of the cell, the contents are: *1.28 ( 3.93%)*.

If I want to get only **3.93** from that cell, what pattern matching should I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap in REGEXEXTRACT:

```
=REGEXEXTRACT(....,"\((.+)%")
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming '1.28 ( 3.93%)' is in A1, this will return '3.93':

```
=index(split(SUBSTITUTE(substitute(substitute(A1,"("," "),")",""),"%","")," "),0,2)
```

Substitute replaces the unwanted chatacters with blanks. Split separates the two remaining values and index picks the second value. You can try replacing A1 with your importhtml formula. That should work.